# Access Converted ItemsSource Objects in Custom User Control Code Behind

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, dependency-properties

I have a question regarding accessing ItemsSource items that have been converted through an IValueConverter. I have an ItemsSource Dependency Property on a custom user control like so:

```
        public IEnumerable ItemsSource
        {
            get { return (IEnumerable)GetValue(ItemsSourceProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ItemsSourceProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemsSourceProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("ItemsSource", typeof(IEnumerable), typeof(ComboboxWithCheckboxes), new PropertyMetadata(null, null));
```

This is bound to a Combo Box in my user control using the following XAML:

```xml
        <ComboBox Name="cbObjects" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0">
            <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                        <CheckBox Content="{Binding ObjectData}" IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected}"
                                  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center" Checked="OnCbObjectCheckBoxChecked" Unchecked="OnCbObjectCheckBoxChecked" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            <ComboBox.ItemsSource>
                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource ObjectToSelectableObjectConverter}">
                    <Binding Path="ItemsSource" ElementName="ThisControl" />
                    <Binding Path="ItemsSource.Count" ElementName="ThisControl"/>
                </MultiBinding>
            </ComboBox.ItemsSource>
        </ComboBox>
```

As you can see, I'm using an `ObectToSelectableObject` converter on the ItemsSource of the ComboBox. This converter takes a `IEnumerable<T>` and converts them into an `IEnumerable<SelectableObject<T>>` where `SelectableObject<T>` contains the properties bound to the checkbox in the DataTemplate (ObjectData, IsSelected).

All of my items show up just fine in my Combo Box and the converter converts the `T` objects into `SelectableObject<T>` with no issue. However, when I try and access the ItemsSource in the code behind, I see that ItemsSource is still of type `IEnumerable<T>` instead of `IEnumerable<SelectableObject<T>>` So I'm unable to set the IsSelected property of these items from code behind like I want.

Is there any way, after converting ItemsSource from another object, to access the new object list that was created by the converter? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

---Edit for more information ---

I'm accessing ItemsSource from the code behind in the following manner:

```
        protected void CheckBox_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
           foreach(var item in ItemsSource)
           {
                Type t = item.GetType();
           }
        }
```

`Type t` end up having the value of the underlying object data that was passed in and not the `SelectableObject<T>` I'm hoping to see.

Comment: How do you "*try and access the ItemsSource in the code behind*"? Please show that code.

Comment: I've added how I'm accessing the ItemsSource in xaml.cs of the User Control.

Comment: Seems you are confusing the ComboBox's ItemsSource and the one of your UserControls. Try `foreach (var item in cbObjects.ItemsSource)`. The UserControl's ItemsSource is obviously not converted.